# Segmentation fault error with structures

Tags: c++, structure

I have no idea where the segmentation error is coming from ... Any ideas?
I am working with structures for an assignment

```
      TestResult testResultFactory(std::string name, double mark)
        {
                //creating an object of TestResult
                TestResult car;
                car.name = name;
                car.mark = mark;

                return car;
        }


    Student studentFactrory(std::string name)
    {
          //Creating an object of student
          Student house;
          house.name = name;
          house.testResults = 0;
          house.numTestResults = 0;

          return house;
    }


void addTestResult(Student * student, std::string testName, double testMark)
{
    //First we need to create a new array
    (student->numTestResults)+=1;
    TestResult *newTestArray = new TestResult[(student->numTestResults)];

    //Now we loop through the old array and add it to the new one
      int index = (student->numTestResults);

          for (size_t i = 0; i < (index-1); i++)
          {
              newTestArray[i] = testResultFactory((student->testResults[i].name),(student->testResults[i].mark));
          }

      //Now we need to add the new student to the end of the array
        newTestArray[index] = testResultFactory(testName, testMark);

        (student->testResults) = newTestArray;
}

string studentBest(Student const * student)
{
    //create variables as temps
    string highestName;
    double highestMark;
    int index = (student->numTestResults);

    //Setting the two variables to the first value
    highestName = (student->testResults[0].name);
    highestMark = (student->testResults[0].mark);

    //Using a while loop to compare and get the best
      for (size_t i = 0; i < index; i++)
      {
          if((student->testResults[i].mark)> highestMark)
          {
            highestMark = (student->testResults[i].mark);
            highestName = (student->testResults[i].name);
          }
      }

    //returning the string they want
    string send = (highestName)+ " "+ doubleToString(highestMark)+ "%";

    return send;
  }


double studentAverage(Student const * student)
{
    //Variables used as temps
    double average = 0;
    double counter = 0.0;
    double running = 0;
    int index = (student->numTestResults);

    //Now we need to loop through each one and add to running and counter
      for (size_t i = 0; i < index; i++)
       {
          counter++;
          running += (student->testResults[i].mark);
       }

    //calculating the average;
    average = (running)/counter;

    return average;
}


void destroyStudent(Student * student)
{
    delete [] (student->testResults);
    (student->testResults)=0;
}


Subject subjectFactory(std::string name)
{
    //Creating an object to use in subject factory
    Subject lamp;

    lamp.name = name;
    lamp.numStudents = 0;
    lamp.studentsAllocated = 0;
    lamp.students = 0;

    return lamp;
}
```

MY guess is that the error occurs because of an out of bounds array or an pointer not worked with correctly .

```
int getStudentIndex(Subject const * subject, std::string studentName)
{
    int index;
    int count = (subject->numStudents);

    //loop to find the names and set index
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(studentName == ((subject->students[i].name)))
        {
          index = i;
        }

        else index = -1;
    }

    return index;
}


void addStudent(Subject * subject, std::string studentName)
{
    //Variables as temps

    Student *pointer =0;
    int index = getStudentIndex(subject,studentName);

    if(index != -1)
    {
    //Now we need to see if they are large enough

    if((subject->studentsAllocated)==0)
    {
      //Set the allocated to 2
        (subject->studentsAllocated) = 2;
        pointer = new Student[2];

        //Figure this out later
        pointer[1] = studentFactrory(studentName);

        (subject->students) = pointer;
    }

    else
      {
        //increase SA with 1.5
          (subject->studentsAllocated) = (subject->studentsAllocated) * 1.5;
          pointer = new Student[(subject->studentsAllocated)+1];
          int count = (subject->studentsAllocated);
          //Now we need to put all the other students in
          for (size_t i = 0; i < count-1; i++)
          {
              pointer[i] = (subject->students[i]);
          }

          pointer[(subject->studentsAllocated)+1] = studentFactrory(studentName);
          (subject->studentsAllocated) += 1 ;
      }

      //Once done just seet one equal to
      (subject->students) = pointer;
  }
  else return;

}

void removeStudent(Subject * subject, std::string studentName)
{
    //First get temps
    int index = getStudentIndex(subject ,studentName);
    int number = (subject->studentsAllocated);
    int i = index;

    //delete student
    if(index == -1) return;

    destroyStudent(&(subject->students)[index]);

    //loop to shift the things
    while (i<(number -1))
    {
        (subject->students)[i] = (subject-> students[i+1]);
    }

    //Removing the last one
    (subject->numStudents) -= 1;
}

bool addTestResult(Subject * subject, std::string studentName, std::string testName, double testMark)
{
    int index = getStudentIndex(subject ,studentName);

    if(index != -1)
    {
      addTestResult(&(subject->students [index]),testName,testMark);
      return true;
    }
  else
      return false;
}

void printSubjectSummary(Subject const * subject)
{
  cout<<(subject->name)<< ": with "<<(subject->numStudents)<<" students"<<endl;
  //Variables to use in the loop
  size_t indexLoop = subject->numStudents;
  int i=0;

    while (i< indexLoop)
    {
        cout<<(subject->students[i].name)<<" Average: "<<studentAverage(&(subject->students[i]))<<", Best: "<<studentBest(&(subject->students[i]))<<endl;
    }
}
void destroySubject(Subject * subject)
{
  //Variables
  size_t indexLoop = subject->numStudents;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < indexLoop; i++)
  {
            destroyStudent(&(subject->students[i]));
    }
    delete [] subject->students;
    subject->students =0;
}
```

I can not seem to find where the segmentation error is coming from.  Even restarted the whole assignment from scratch and still seem to get errors.

Can someone please help or indicate where the fault could be coming from.

Over here we have the structs.h file that is included in my code above

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H

struct TestResult{
    double mark;//the test mark as a percentage
    std::string name;//the test name
};
struct Student{
    std::string name;
    TestResult * testResults;//an arry of TestResults
    size_t numTestResults;//the number of results for this student (also the size of the array)
};
struct Subject{
    std::string name;
    Student * students;//an array of Students
    size_t numStudents;//the number of students added to the subject
    size_t studentsAllocated;//the size of the Student arry(must never be smaller that numStudents)
};

#endif
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What does the actual crash say? can you post the stacktrace as well?

Comment: Why is _array of Stdents_ a pointer and not a std::vector?

Comment: Why is there a studentFactrory, that does what the constructor should do?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many logical errors in there that the root cause (or causes; there are quite a few candidates) could be pretty much anywhere.

`getStudentIndex` returns -1 unless the student is the last one in the array, and an indeterminate value for the first one you add, so adding the first student to a subject is undefined.

`addStudent` only adds a student if they're already taking the subject.

It also (for some inexplicable reason) allocates an array of two `Students`, leaving the first element uninitialised.
Using this first element is, of course, undefined.

In the other branch, it first claims that the number of allocated students is `* 1.5`, but then only allocates `+ 1`.
This will undoubtedly lead to problems.

There is a recursion in `addTestResult` that will never terminate.

There are most likely other problems as well – this was just a quick glance.
Start with fixing these.

And do learn about constructors and destructors so you can get rid of those "factory" and "destroy" functions.